# Cannot import qgis.core to python

Tags: python, qgis

I'm new to Python. I want to create GIS app with Python using QGIS library on Window 7 64bit.

The way I do:

- install QGIS 1.7.0
- I set ***PYTHONPATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python***
- I run python from Python exist in here ***D:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\bin***
- I type import qgis.core, a pop up window appear with text "

> The program can't start because qgis_core.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

" and text in cmd is "

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

"

Thank in advance.

Comment: I'd guess you'll need to adjust `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH`: http://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg04200.html

Comment: I read that link and change PATH, PYTHONPATH, but nothing changes.
Could you show me clearly !
Thank so much.

Comment: Responded here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334000/dll-load-failed-with-pyqgis/25269980#25269980