# DLL load failed with PyQGIS

Tags: python-2.7, qgis

I've already asked this question in the "gis.stackexchange" forum, but it seems to be more appropriate for this one.

I am having problems with Python Shell importing the module "qgis.core".
When I type "import qgis.core" the Shell ("idle.pyw") gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato (Trad "Impossible to find the specified module").
```

I have already set the environment to point the right folders following "PyQGIS cookbook" instructions.
In my case, the paths are:

PYTHOPATH=C:\"QGIS_path"\apps\qgis\python;
Path=C:\"QGIS_path"\apps\qgis\bin.

Am I missing something? What are supposed to be the right libraries the Shell is unable to find?
I am working with windows 7 64 bit, QGIS Lisboa (version 1.8), Python 2.7.2 (the one that is included in the QGIS package).

Comment: Probably you will find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765800/django-error-for-psycopg2-importerror-dll-load-failed) useful, it sounds similar.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like to mix my python installations, so I add the paths on the fly.
  The paths you need are below:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend([r"C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps",r"C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\bin",r"C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27"])

import qgis.core
```

Comment: This hack works for some resources, but not all.  If you want to use all QGIS resources, use its own Python installation from your IDE (or from within QGIS itself)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [import-qgis-core-in-pycharm-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtcore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337558/import-qgis-core-in-pycharm-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtcore)
also ignore the pycharm setup if you want.

It works for me,

setup-qgispy.bat

`@ECHO off
    set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\QGIS
    call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
    call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
    call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"
    path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
    set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
    set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
    set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
    set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
    set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
    set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
    set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
    set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%
    set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
    set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis`

and then,

C:\> setup-qgispy.bat

C:\> python file.py

Answer (score -2):

I think instead of sys.path.extend(). Copy the sys.path from qgis python console and use it. Hope this will work.