# from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry. DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, 64-bit, environment-variables, qgis

I recently installed QGIS and I want to import qgis module of Python. I use Windows 7 x64 and QGIS 2.2 x64. I set the PATH to :

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib;C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;E:\Python\GeoDjango\myplanet;E:\Python\GeoDjango\myplanet;C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python\qgis;
```

and PYTHONPATH to:

```
C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\python\2.7\site-packages;E:\Python\GeoDjango\myplanet;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27\lib;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27\DLLs;
```

I still get this error:

```
    import qgis
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I used Dependency Walker to track the problems with the DLL load.
this is the screenshot of Dependency Walker:
[image]

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

How can I fix the errors?

Comment: You've got spaces after some of your semicolons. Do they matter?

Comment: I don't think they are important but I'll try and report it to you. Thanks

Comment: WoW! yes! Now I get different error. I'll update the question now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731786/pycairo-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: @lxanezis Question updated again. Will you take a look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

See here:  [DLL load failed with PyQGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334000/dll-load-failed-with-pyqgis/25269980#25269980)

```
import sys
sys.path.extend([r"C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps",r"C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\bin",r"C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27"])

import qgis.core
```

Answer (score 0):

i use pycharm as my IDE now, my solution is just set the "python-qgis.bat" as the python interpreter, the .bat file's path is "~\qgis\bin". check out this bat file you'll find that all the paths have been set in this.bat file. hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I am a beginner in python (and Qgis) but I read in the guide that qgis.core is not in a dll.
The first part "qgis" is a directory e the second part is a file "core.pyd"
You add at your PYTHONPATH variable the directory where is qgis (dir).
for me is: PHYTONPATH="C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python"
I hope I have been of help!!